# Необходимость использования указателей и ссылок в разных случаях

Tags: c++

В процессе познания основ программирования столкнулся с очередной проблемой: не до конца понимаю область применения ссылок и указателей.
В связи с этим несколько вопросов:

- Зачем указатель или ссылку использовать при названиии некоторой функции или метода класса?
- Для решения каких именно задач нам необходимо возвращать ссылку или указатель (на объект, например)?

Прошу объяснить на примере этого кода и по возможности привести свои примеры.

```
monstr & the_best(monstr &M){
if(health > M.health) return *this;
return M;
}
... monstr Vasia(50), Super(200);
monstr Best = Vasia.the_best(Super);
```

Дополнительные вопросы по коду выше:

- Зачем, собственно, здесь используется ссылка в назывании метода?
- Что выполняет последняя строка кода?

Comment: Я бы ответил так: если будете изучать как положено, т:е. читать побольше и писать примеры, то поймете гораздо лучше, чем услышать какие то обьяснения в нескольких предложениях...

Answer (score 1):

"При названии" — это имеется в виду тот самый `monstr &` перед названием функции `the_best`?

Традиционно в языках C-семейства со статической типизацией перед названием функции идет возвращаемый ею тип. В данном случае, функция имеет тип `monstr &`, то есть возвращает ссылку на монстра. На какого именно монстра будет указывать эта ссылка — это, собственно, и есть содержание этой функции.

> Для решения каких именно задач нам необходимо возвращать ссылку или указатель (на объект, например)?

Too broad. Для каких угодно, вернее, задача предполагается одна: произвести какое-то действие над этим объектом.

Например, вызвать еще один его метод:

```
struct Monster {
    Monster &eat() { return *this; }
    Monster &sleep() { return *this; }
    Monster &growl() { return *this; }
    Monster &operator=(Monster const &that) { return *this; }
};

Monster frank;
frank.eat().sleep().growl();
```

Несколько методов вызваны в одном выражении.

В частности, возвращать ссылку на себя является де-факто стандартом для оператора присваивания, что позволяет производить несколько присваиваний в одном выражении, как это с незапамятных времен делалось в C:

```
Monster frank, hulk, predator, alien;
alien = predator = hulk = frank; // devour them all
```

Еще можно много об этом говорить, вопрос too broad.